# Wireshark does not capture all packets in the network

Tags: wireshark

In my Windows box, Wireshark captures all the packets of the network. But in Linux (Ubuntu) It is capturing my outgoing and incoming packets only. How can it be resolved in Linux? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to your network card not being in promiscuous mode. The reason might be that the drivers don't support it, or the card itself doesn't support it.

See this: http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q7.6

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Actually I have a broadcom driver. I had to install a b43fw-cutter to setup the wifi. If you know something about this please leave a comment. Thank you!

Comment: I've only had brief dealings with `b43fw-cutter`, but from my experience I would say that you shouldn't count on decent Broadcom support in Linux. I'm also pretty sure that the Broadcom chipset doesn't natively support promiscuous mode.